# Creating a new column based on TRUE/FALSE of several columns in R

Tags: r

I am new in R and this is my first post. Please help me out.

I have a dataset that has 10 columns that look like this:

| Red | Blue | Green |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | False |
| True | False | False |
| False | True | False |
| False | False | True |

I want one column that should look like:

| Color |
| --- |
| Red |
| Red |
| Blue |
| Green |

The 'True' should be read into that color. Only one 'True' across columns in a given row.

I tried: `df <- df %>% add_column(color=ifelse(.$col_name == TRUE,colnames(df)[1],"")`

| Red | Blue | Green | col_1 | col_2 | col_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| True | False | False | Red |  |  |
| True | False | False | Red |  |  |
| False | True | False |  | Blue |  |
| False | False | True |  |  | Green |

Thus creating 10 extra columns with a hope to merge them later. But I am stuck. Can anyone please help?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are `tidyverse` approaches.

```
df = tibble(Red = c(T,T,F,F), Blue = c(F,F,T,F), Green = c(F,F,F,T))
```

**Approach 1:** `case_when`, a vectorised multiple if - else.

```
df %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(Red ~ "Red",
                           Blue ~ "Blue",
                           Green ~ "Green"))
```

Swap `mutate` with `transmute` to only return the new `color` column.
**Approach 2:** Use column name properties.

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "color") %>%
  filter(value) %>%
  select(color)
```

**Approach 3:** subset column names

```
df %>%
  mutate(color = names(.)[apply(., 1, which)])
```

Comment: This solves the problem from the beginning. I did not have to merge later. Sleek and clear solution. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a logical dataframe:

```
cbind(df, col = names(df)[max.col(df1)])
    Red  Blue Green   col
1  True False False   Red
2  True False False   Red
3 False  True False  Blue
4 False False  True Green
```

On the other hand, if you have data as presented above, then:

```
df1 <- df #THIS IS TO ENSURE YOU MAINTAIN YOUR ORIGINAL DATAFRAME
df1[]<-as.logical(as.matrix(df1))

cbind(df1, color = names(df)[max.col(df1)])

    Red  Blue Green color
1  TRUE FALSE FALSE   Red
2  TRUE FALSE FALSE   Red
3 FALSE  TRUE FALSE  Blue
4 FALSE FALSE  TRUE Green
```

If copying the data is expensive then:

```
cbind(df, col = names(df)[max.col(array(as.logical(unlist(df)), dim(df)))])
```

Comment: Thank you. It was helpful and solved the problem.

Comment: Surprised to see `max.col(array(as.logical(unlist(df, use.names = F)), dim(df)))` is ~3 x faster than `apply(df, 1, which)` , nice solution!

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach, using `ifelse`:

```
df$col_1 <- ifelse(df$Red, "Red", "")
df$col_2 <- ifelse(df$Blue, "Blue", "")
df$col_3 <- ifelse(df$Green, "Green", "")
```